# Mysterious Screensaver functionality despite correct power settings

Tags: 22.04, screensaver

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and ever since my screen turns off after about 20 seconds of inactivity and turns right back on when I press a key or move the mouse. This doesn't happen if there's a video playing, so it likely has to be something intelligent like a screensaver. All settings in "Power" are turned off, "Screen blanking" set to never, etc. Is there anything else that I could have missed? This does not happen when I boot from an Ubuntu 22.04 USB image.

Or maybe someone could tell me what logs to check to find out what is causing this? I already checked dmesg and there's nothing shown there when it happens.

Comment: what are the Screen Saver and DPMS sections in the output of `xset q` in terminal?

Comment: @vanadium probably not the BIOS as it doesn't happen with USB boot

Comment: @Andra here it is `Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
`

Comment: if you run `xset s off`, does it change this behaviour?

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: you say that all settings are off, but have you tried to set "on", change time,  and then "off" ?

Comment: Yes I tried that in the Ubuntu power settings. Also tried restarting since, didn't help unfortunately.